# Is there an etymological relationship between Cartesian and words like carte?

Tags: etymology

"Cartesian space" refers to a [coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) that is sometimes referred to as a ***map***. It is named after [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes).

Meanehile, the french word for "map" is "carte."

Is there any relationship? Or coincidence?

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Comment: @curiousdannii. Has your own research led to a plausible etymology for the toponym "Les Cartes"? Mine has not.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, “Cartesian” is from the Latinised form of the family name “Descartes”. This derives from the one-time place name “Les Cartes”. So “Descartes” means “from (the place called) Les Cartes”. However, I have not found any satisfactory explanation for this toponym. It could be from the plural of carte,  “playing card, map”, but this does not sound like a very plausible name for a village.

Otherwise, do you know if Descartes himself (writing of course in Latin) ever referred to the co-ordinate system as a “charta”? Maybe you would get a better answer in the “History of science and mathematics" forum.